# i need file upload function. but when i run this code then show this type error

Tags: php, html, file-upload

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
/*if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}*/

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

File is an image - image/jpeg.
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/IMG-20191002-WA0009.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\resume\uploads\upload.php on line 46

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "C:\xampp\tmp\php8F79.tmp" to "uploads/IMG-20191002-WA0009.jpg" in C:\xampp\htdocs\resume\uploads\upload.php on line 46
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to use `../uploads/` as a path instead of `uploads/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try an absolute path, by replacing:

```php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

With something like:

```
$target_dir = __DIR__ . '/uploads/';
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are not set correctly and the form tag is missing. All should be declared after the post event by clicking the submit button:

```
$imageFileType = "";
$target_file = "";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

if($check !== false) {
  echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".<br>";
  $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
  echo "File is not an image.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
/*if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}*/

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
  echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
  echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
}
print "<FORM  action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}'  method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
?>
<input type="file"  name="fileToUpload"/>
<?php
print "<button type='submit' name='submit' style='width:100px;'>upload</button>";
print "</form>";
```